# Healed while knocked out

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, unconscious

Tonight at my party's session, I was being attacked by an army of angry island gladiators and I was knocked out - dropped to 0 HP with a non-lethal attack.
I have Devotee's Censer with me and I activated the healing property before being knocked out.
The question is, when I am healed with the 1d4 dice at the start of my next turn, will I regain consciousness or not?

Answer (score 6):

### Yes

From the [combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat) rules:

> **Falling Unconscious**
>
> If damage reduces you to 0 Hit Points and fails to kill you, you fall Unconscious (see Conditions ). This unconsciousness ends if you regain any Hit Points.

Provided you are still within range of the incense at the start of your turn you will regain consciousness.